# Mongoose starting and aborting a transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I'm trying to understand how to begin and undo a transaction. I thought `session.abortTransaction()` would cause all the updates in the transaction to undo, in this case, just `Profile.updateOne`. But after I ran the code below, `Profile` 1's username was changed to `'phoebe2'`. Since the transaction was aborted, I'd still expect the username to be the old username.

How do you undo a transaction?

```js
const session = await mongoose.startSession();

await session.startTransaction();

await Profile.updateOne({ _id: '1' }, { username: 'phoebe2' });

// undo transaction

await session.abortTransaction();
await session.endSession();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass `session` as the last argument in `updateOne`

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
await session.startTransaction();

await Profile.updateOne({ _id: '1' }, { username: 'phoebe2' },{session});

// undo transaction

await session.abortTransaction();
await session.endSession();
```